# How can I display custom user information on a page that is not a profile page?

Tags: hooks, users

I'm looking to display User information on an individual page, pulling custom fields to display the information.

For example, if a visitor of the site come across a user page, it would display:

- Name (not username)
- Pictures that they've uploaded
- An about me paragraph

Maybe a few other custom fields in the future, but the main part is that I need to know how to call these from Drupal.

I'm new to Drupal, but I've worked with Wordpress and Joomla a lot in the past and I'm looking to move onto Drupal, so please, be patronising when you explain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you want to achieve this. Using Panels and Views (as suggested by Dmitry Vyal) you can easily build this without writing a single line of code.

No matter which solution to use, you will need to understand [entities](https://drupal.org/node/1261744) (users are entities) and [fields](https://drupal.org/node/443536) (data attached to entities). Both are basic concepts you will find everywhere in Drupal.

If you want to do it in code, you should [create a custom module](https://drupal.org/node/361112) and [understand Drupal hooks system](https://drupal.org/node/292). In this nodule, you can declare a page available at a specific by implementing the [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) hook. Since you want to display information from a user on this page, you will need to include `%user` in your page's path. Combine this with the `'page arguments'` property of your menu item to receive the user object as argument of your page handler function (ie/ the `'page callback'` property of the menu item).

- To retrieve the displayable username of a user, use [`format_username($account)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_username/7).
- To retrieve the picture uploaded by the user, the simpler solution is to query the `file_managed` table where the `uid` column contains the ID of the uploading user. You can then use [`theme('image', array(...))`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) or [`theme('image_style', array(...))`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) to display the images.
- To retrieve a formatted field (such as an formatted text *About me* field), uses [`field_view_value()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7). But to display several fields at once, the best is probably to declare a dedicated view mode in an [`hook_entity_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7) implementation (or re-use an existing ones) and then use [`user_view($account, $view_mode)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_view/7).

Comment: Sounds great, thank-you for the information. I've been having a difficult time with the Drupal documentation, finding where to start on something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should create a panel with two views. One for a general user information and other for stuff like uploaded pictures.

Hope these tutorials will allow you to get started

http://nodeone.se/sv/node/20

http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode32